# Associated Products Missing in STEP 4: Summary page in Explorer, but are visible in Chrome

Tags: magento2.3, image, associated-products

I have used Explorer for years to load items, then load assets including images based on Color attributes.

Upon reaching Step 4: Summary page, I have a view of all children, including those that magento thinks it should create (another subject...)

I then use the view of all children with images as a last review to ensure I have selected the correct main image.

ISSUE:

The view recently stopped working in this manner. It is only showing the missing child that magento seems to think I should have created, or a blank screen.

I have gone to Chrome,and found that it is showing the images correctly.

Why did Explorer stop showing all the children, but Chrome has not?

Scenario on the attached:
I have loaded images on children based on Color Attributes of White and Black
The Black has S, M, L, XL and the White has S, ML, L, XL, 2XL

The screen shots show the view in Explorer-top image (incorrect view) and Chrome- bottom image (correct view)
.[image]
I am emphasizing that the Correct view is what I am used to seeing and what I would like to continue to see.

Also note that this is issue is not related to loading images based on attribute choice. The issue is still in place when choosing all skus.